# How do I mod_rewrite domains pointing to my origin server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

How do I rewrite all domains pointing to my Origin Server - To my Domain Name? I want to prevent other Domains hosting my content!

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys this is help for anyone who has a problem with other domains pointing to there Origin IP and is getting indexed higher then them and so on! The first thing you will need to do

Is make sure in your httpd.conf file that mod_rewrite.so module is enabled

```
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And you must also make sure that you are allowing the .htaccess file to Override all:

```
 # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All
```

Once this is done you can either setup a 301 permanent redirect - so in my case all you need to do is setup the forwader of "www." "yourdomain.com" and forward this to the rewrite so https:// or http:// of "yourdomain.com". You can do this in your page settings of your DNS manager or copy this code as well into your .htaccess file under your Rewrite Condition

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^https://yourdomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.my-domain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Now as you can see that I have setup a rewrite for https:// connections - If you want to rewrite http just remove the S and so fourth!

My question is now I have no idea how to stop my "targetdomain.com" being able to access my origins data at all!